# Sequentinal split

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file which looks something like this :

Thanks And Regards

Comment: where are you removing `row_n` from the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
awk -F\| '{f=($1 ".json"); $1=(a[f]==0)?"[":","; print > f; a[f]++} END {for (f in a) {printf "]\n" > f}}' file
```

it removes `row_n` from the output by replacing it, keeps track of the filenames to add the trailing `]`.

The format is a bit off (commas on next line) but valid json which you can make prettier with `jq`

```
jq <row_2.json
```

```
[
  {
    "abc": 5,
    "cda": 6
  },
  {
    "efg": 7,
    "hij": 8
  }
]
```

Comment: Very similar to the code you posted, with some difference: replaces `$1` with either `[` or `,` depending on whether that `$1` was seen before (`a[f]`). At the end, the final `]` is written to each file.

Comment: To pass a variable to `awk` use `-v var=value` (see `man awk`)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F\| '                         # set field separator
$1!=f {                              # when $1 changes
    if(NR>1) {                       # and its not the first record
        print b "]" > f              # output buffer with ending bracket
        close(f)                     # close file
    }
    f=$1                             # filename is the first field
    b="["                            # buffer the opening bracket
}
{
    b=b (b=="["?"":"," ORS) $2       # buffer records
}
END {                                # in the end
    print b "]">f                    # flush the buffer and the closing bracket
}' file
```

Output:

```
$ cat row_1
[{abc:1,cda:2},
{efg:3,hij:4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, essentially all that `sed` can do, can be done in awk. This assumes your orriginal file is sorted by the first column:

```
awk -F "|" '($1 != p) && rec { rec= rec "]"
                               print rec > (p".json);
                               close(p".json")
                               rec="" }
            { rec = rec (rec=="" ? "[" : "," ORS) $2; p=$1 }
            END { rec = rec "]"; print rec > (p".json"); close (p".json") }' file
```